# Maintain order when using SQLite WHERE-clause and IN operator

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

Consider the following `tbl`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INTEGER, ticker TEXT, desc TEXT);

INSERT INTO tbl (ID, ticker, desc) 
    VALUES (1, 'GDBR30', '30YR'),
           (2, 'GDBR10', '10YR'),
           (3, 'GDBR5', '5YR'),
           (4, 'GDBR2', '2YR');
```

For reference, `tbl` looks like this:

```
ID   ticker   desc
1    GDBR30   30YR
2    GDBR10   10YR
3    GDBR5    5YR
4    GDBR2    2YR
```

When issuing the following statement, the result will be ordered according to `ID`.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE ticker in ('GDBR10', 'GDBR5', 'GDBR30')

ID   ticker   desc
1    GDBR30   30YR
2    GDBR10   10YR
3    GDBR5    5YR
```

However, I need the ordering to adhere to the order of the passed list of values. Here's what I am looking for:

```
ID   ticker   desc
2    GDBR10   10YR
3    GDBR5    5YR
1    GDBR30   30YR
```

Comment: Always include ORDER BY clause in your query when ordering the result is of importance for a consumer. Never rely on the other parts of the query.

Comment: "When issuing the following statement, the result will be ordered according to ID". No, it is ordered in whatever way the engine gets the data. Without an `ORDER BY` there is no guarantee about the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `CTE` that returns 2 columns: the values that you search for and for each value the sort order and join it to the table.
In the `ORDER BY` clause use the sort order column to sort the results:

```
WITH cte(id, ticker) AS (VALUES (1, 'GDBR10'), (2, 'GDBR5'), (3, 'GDBR30'))
SELECT t.* 
FROM tbl t INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.ticker = t.ticker
ORDER BY c.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fb4f4479b4c7748e0be698a72e78778c).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be sure of the final ordering of records is to use the `ORDER BY` clause.

The order the list of values is given is not relevant for final ordering.

In your case your only solution is to give to each value a 'weight' to use as sort order.

You could for example change the `IN` operator with a `INSTR` function to get both a filterable and a sortable result.

Try something like that

```
SELECT *, INSTR(',GDBR10,GDBR5,GDBR30,', ',' || ticker || ',') POS
FROM tbl
WHERE POS>0
ORDER BY POS;
```

If you don't want the position in the selected fields list you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, INSTR(',GDBR10,GDBR5,GDBR30,', ',' || ticker || ',') pos FROM tbl) X
WHERE  POS>0
ORDER BY POS;
```

Comment: Almost like a RECURSIVE query within the `INSTR` function - really nice (+1)!